# wpf datagrid adding items synchronously

Tags: wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF Datagrid on my project. When user uploads documents(or selects folder) into program datagrid is being loaded by the document's whole properties(text, type, uri etc.). Especially when user gives a folder to program it freezes for a time till it loads every folder. And on final step it populates the datagrid.

The thing I really want to do is that loading datagrid rows as soon as a file is loaded successfully not at the end of the last process.

Could you show me some way..

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried updating the DatGrid on a different thread?

here's an example of how it's done in WPF:

```
// Places the delegate onto the UI Thread's Dispatcher
private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // Place delegate on the Dispatcher.
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
        new TimerDispatcherDelegate(TimerWorkItem));
}
```

taken from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx)

Comment: actually i have never used dispatcher class. And couldn't find what exactly will work. What does this mean inside method? and should I call this timer_Elapsed from somewhere? where? thank you..

Comment: This is the WPF way of using a different thread for UI elements.
the timer_Elapsed event is just an example, you should use your own event or function that is relevant to the datagrid.
like, when the file is loaded successfully as you said.